# how to create batch file with communication to other files

Tags: batch-file

```
set var x=1
set var y=1
call (tank_stats) if (metal) is present y+1=y
```

i need help on knowing if there a code for this that will change the var value depending on how many file named the name required to increase the value and then i want to know if there a way for files to communicate and be able to destroy each other like say if i use this code

> if (forgin file) in folder (battle) x>y then (delete or break this
>   file) display message creature destroyed

Comment: please help me im trying to create a small mini game and kinda have a programmer battle with my friends i just need to know some of the basic code for this communication and stuff and then me and my friends can try to make more advance stuff on are own so please help us

Comment: is there also a way to send it to like a website thing or something if its not safe doing it on each other school computer

Comment: Programs communicate via files. Reading and writing. They can also send messages. See `Waitfor /?` to synchronise file access.

Comment: The answer to all of your questions is YES there is a way to do that, but you are going to need to do a lot of googling!  Welcome to programming. You are gonna have fun.  Continue to build cool things with your friends! To answer your questions we will need to know what you have tried and what errors you got or what didn't work.  Please be specific.

Comment: i basically did the code up there and then was going to type in his user of the shared network cause its a school computer and the send to a designated folder all i was wonder what is the code for it to read how many file of a certain type there was and then have it break those file and permanently have its y and x changed or what i really have it stand -

Comment: for is attack and def. i was wondering what would i call the foreign file or the file he created with out know its name like say if all creature files or cards had like a certain code which they only communicated with each other then and will only check those for the if statement about x>y -

Comment: because basically this only one of the many problems there is how the resources for upgrading your creature but i think i can figure it out and then there how to make other files not be destroyed so it would be like fight over resources or land by using file and then placing a file that --

Comment: access that lock file that is making the resources and that file is like a claim flag and can be destroyed and then how to be able to put creatures to defend it even if i could destroy it with one hit it has to go through my creature to get to it i got most of the code down by think of how to use var and if then and other basic code but that  only gets me so far i made a file copy a file once before i ran into a error after run that file it again cause i don't know a code for having something loop every so mins. i had already google i much as i can but i dont find my answer.

Comment: is waitfor /? the code i need to have it have files change its variables

Comment: will you test this code for me and tell me what i did wrong

Comment: (creature code) {set var x=1} {set var y=1} {check (tank_stats) if (metal) then y+1=y also (gunpowder) then x+1=x} if any var change then copy and paste (tank) to (creature folder) and delete current file} or if i have the file ruining the whole time it loop and checks and always change the stats and make them visable but the echo text will be paused to read

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review the FAQs on [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and then see if you can edit your question for better clarity and conciseness. Your question will be better received if you keep it, and your code, confined to your original post. Good luck.